# ERROR - secure_channel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_scopes' with .to_dataframe() on bigquery object

Tags: python, pip, google-bigquery, six

**Environment Details**

- Python 3.7.12
- google-api-core 1.23.0
- google-auth 1.35.0
- bigquery 2.3.1
- let me know if i can provide any other library versions

We are querying some data from bigquery using python in airflow, and converting results into a dataframe. See this chunk of code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
bq = bigquery.Client()
query_result = bq.query(f"select count(*) as num_rows from our_project.ourdataset.our_table")
our_df = query_result.to_dataframe()
```

`query_result` is a `<google.cloud.bigquery.job.query.QueryJob object at`

When we run the last line `our_df = query_result.to_dataframe()`, we get the error `TypeError: secure_channel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_scopes'`. The whole error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py", line 1313, in to_dataframe
    date_as_object=date_as_object,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py", line 1695, in to_dataframe
    create_bqstorage_client=create_bqstorage_client,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py", line 1510, in to_arrow
    bqstorage_client = self.client._create_bqstorage_client()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 446, in _create_bqstorage_client
    return bigquery_storage.BigQueryReadClient(credentials=self._credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_storage_v1/services/big_query_read/client.py", line 386, in __init__
    or Transport == type(self).get_transport_class("grpc_asyncio")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_storage_v1/services/big_query_read/transports/grpc.py", line 170, in __init__
    ("grpc.max_receive_message_length", -1),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery_storage_v1/services/big_query_read/transports/grpc.py", line 221, in create_channel
    **kwargs,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 286, in create_channel
    return grpc_gcp.secure_channel(target, composite_credentials, **kwargs)
TypeError: secure_channel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_scopes'
```

This line of code was previously working for us. The only change I recall us making since the code was last working was:

- Installed `dbt==0.19.0`

`to.data_frame()` seems like the most basic python function there is, and it is quite frustrating that it is not working here for us. What can we do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the issue, but I have no idea how to resolve. `dbt-bigquery 0.19.0 depends on google-api-core<1.24 and >=1.16.0` When we installed `dbt`, it must have changed the `google-api-core` version from something greater, down to 1.23.0. However, `google-api-core` being as low as 1.23 is now causing this other issue with `to_dataframe()`. I know this because when I manually upgraded `google-api-core` to 1.26, `.to_dataframe()` was working again.

**EDIT:** upgrading dbt to 0.20.0 allows for google-api-core 1.3+, which resolves our issue!

Answer (score 0):

For me upgrading `google-auth`, `google-auth-httplib2`, and `google-api-core` did the trick.